# Error: values.map is not a function ( why I get this error )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, express

i am fetching details from database through Id wanted to display that into the table, but for initial purpose i wanted to just display on browser without table and stuff.. am getting values.map is not a function but when I did console.log(values), got {title: "", description: "", tags: "", photo: "", loading: false, …}
createdBlog: ""
description: ""
error: ""
formData: ""
getaRedirect: false
loading: false
photo: ""
tags: ""
title: ""
**proto**: Object

what to do, please help

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../../styles.css";
import { getoneBlog } from "../helper/coreapicalls";
import ImageHelper from "../helper/ImageHelper";

const Fullblog = ({ match }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
    tags: "",
    photo: "",
    loading: false,
    error: "",
    createdBlog: "",
    getaRedirect: false,
    formData: "",
  });

  const {
    title,
    description,
    tags,
    loading,
    error,
    createdBlog,
    getaRedirect,
    formData,
  } = values;

  const preload = (blogId) => {
    getoneBlog(blogId).then((data) => {
      //console.log(data);
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
      } else {
        // preloadCategories();
        setValues({
          ...values,
          title: data.title,
          description: data.description,
          tags: data.tags,
          formData: new FormData(),
        });
      }
    });
  };

  console.log(values);

  

  useEffect(() => {
    preload(match.params.blogId);
  }, []);

  

  

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="py-md-5 py-3">
        <div className="Fullblog ">
          {values.map((fullblog, index) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <h1 className="FullblogTittle">
                  Founder Leandra Medine Cohen announced the news to her
                  employees on a Zoom call earlier this week.
                  {fullblog.title}
                </h1>
                <p className="tags">tags </p>
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/17/17/41/girl-5662873_960_720.jpg"
                  className="FullblogImg"
                  alt="img"
                />
                <ImageHelper />
                <p className="description">
                  CULTURE How to Celebrate Halloween at Home This Year From
                  horror movie marathons to Halloween-themed drive-in features
                  to virtual pumpkin carving parties, here's how to celebrate
                  Halloween safely this year. By Pahull Bains Date October 22,
                  2020 With cases on the rise in certain regions of Ontario ’s A
                  Little Blurry. The livestream will be viewable on demand for
                  24 hours for ticket holders. Get your tickets here.
                </p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Fullblog;
```

coreapicalls code-

```
// get all Blogs
export const getBlogs = () => {
  return fetch(`${API}/blogs`, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

//get a Blog
export const getoneBlog = (blogId) => {
  return fetch(`${API}blog/${blogId}`, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` function on an Array but your state looks to be set up as an Object rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

Check these lines:

```
{values.map((fullblog, index) => {
```

&

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({ ... });  // This is an object
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling `array`.

So the issue is, you are trying the `map()` on an object that's why it is showing you the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use .map() on Array variables, as mentioned before.

You can simply do this:

**Object.keys(values)**, which will make an Array with the keys of your object.

```
Object.keys(values).map( keys => console.log(values[key]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You used object destructuring on `values` but there is no such method as `Object.prototype.map`...
You can loop over `Object.values(values)` with map or `Object.keys(values)` if you want to loop over the keys.
Code:

```js
Object.values(values).map((fullblog, index) => {
    // insert code here
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your valuable reply, Can you show me the correct code ...! Please

Comment: ooh,but after doing that I'm not getting values like - titile,tags,description, I'm still confuse..! please help

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: sir, as you know I have two API - ${API}/blogs and ${API}/blog/${blogId} ,The first API displays all the blogs that I have on my mongodb database, but I want to, when someone clicks on any of my blog, they will reach on that particular blog using my second API, I hope you understand what i'm trying to say, please help,  @expressjs123